# Domains not updating?

Tags: krl

I attempted to add another dispatch domain to a Kynetx app yesterday and could not get the app to fire on the new domain. I've seen some lag on domain updating before (usually limited to an hour or so), so I decided to wait a day and see if it updated.

After about 24 hours, the app still will not fire on the new domain. So, I removed a domain that had been in the app for a while to make sure I was not me making a typo (if it was a typo, the app would update correctly and would not fire on the removed domain). Unfortunately, it still fires on the domain that was removed.

So now the app fires on a domain *not* listed in the dispatch{} section, but doesn't fire on one that *is* listed. I have tried the testing version of the app and the production (deployed) version, but both have this same problem.

Any ideas? Anyone know of downtime with Kynetx's dispatch domains server?

Update: the app also fires on a google search to annotate the results from the same domains in the dispatch. This is also not working. I have added a few more domains, and the app does not fire on any of them.

Update:
**select statements**:

```
 select using "google.com|bing.com|yahoo.com" setting()
```

for the search annotation

```
select using ".*"
foreach datasource:spreadsheet("&sq=domain%3D" + page:url("domain")).pick("$.feed.entry") setting (site)
```

for rule that fires on that domain.

Keep in mind, I didn't make any changes to the select statements or rules.

**New domains I added, to both the spreadsheet datasource and the dispatch domains**:

3flamingosyogurt.com

massageenvy.com

abcapartmentsolutions.com

worldsoffun.com

Comment: How are you running the application? Universal browser extension, single purpose browser extension, site tags, bookmarklet?

Comment: If you're running it from a bookmarklet, it shouldn't be a problem with the dispatch block, since bookmarklets disregard that. Are you sure it's not a problem with your select statements?

Comment: @Steve Nay, I would agree, if there were any problems with previous domains. The app fires on any domain that was there before the new domains.

Comment: If you are using a bookmarklet, your issue most likely has nothing to do with the dispatch block. I think you will need to share your select statements and the urls that you are trying to get your app to work on for us to help you some more.

Comment: @Mike it's the Acxiom discount app, if that sheds any more light on the issue. It looks like you worked on it a while back?

Comment: haha! Yes I did indeed work on that app. Was over 200 apps ago though. : ) What is the rid so I can check to see if I have access to it.

Comment: The id is a279x1. It looks like you should still have access to it.

Comment: Tidbit of info: I added the domains to the datasource with www. on them. I also found one that was there before with www. and it didn't work properly, either. So removed all the www. (from the ones I added and the one that had it before). I changed the "cachable for" on the datasource from 1 year to 1 minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story, short: The Google Doc datasource had been set to not republish itself upon updating.

There were other complicating factors, but I'll leave those out for now :).

Moral of the story is always republish your datasources.